# Unpacking a tuple with dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple with multiple dictionaries and I wish to unpack them for further use.

Let's say I have this:

```
tuple_to_add = {'name': 'custom1', 'value': 'first value'},{'name': 'custom2', 'value': 'second value'}
```

And I'd like to iterate through them
I tried something like that but it didn't give me my answer:

```
    for value, name in tuple_to_add:
       print(value)
       print(name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries can't be unpacked in a way tuples and lists can. If you had a tuple of tuples, your way of printing would work just fine:

```
tuple_to_add = ('custom1', 'first value'), ('custom2', 'second value')
for name, value in tuple_to_add:
    # do whatever you want
```

You can simply iterate over the tuple and get the actual dictionary objects which you can use to get all the necessary information:

```
for dc in tuple_to_add:
    print(dc['value'])
    print(dc['name'])
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll do!

Comment: Just think of the type of each element as you iterate over your tuple. Each element is a dict, so treat it as a dict.